# Context-free grammar for $L=\{ a^nb^m | n \le m+3 \}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm having problems determining the *productions* for a CFG describing the language $L=\{ a^nb^m | n \le m+3 \}$

where $n,m \ge 0$

I'm very new to this so this example might be a little harder, but everything I try I end up not finding the correct solutions. Some example strings are $\epsilon$, $a$, $aa$, $aaa$, $b$, $ab$, $aab$, $aaab$, $aaaab$, $bb$, $abb$, $aabb$, $aaabb$, $aaaabb$, $aaaaabb$ etc.

This is how I tried reasoning:

since there can be a loop of $a$ in the beginning, I thought that *one* production could be

$A \rightarrow aAb | \epsilon$

But this is as far as my reasoning goes. What's confusing is that for each value of $m$, I have increasing $n$.

Can anyone give a hint, or give general hints how to construct CFG from languages?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $L = a^n b^n\,bbb\,b^*$

Comment: @Pseudonym This gives $m \ge n+3$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Is that supposed to be a regular expression? Since we have $a^nb^n$ and $b*$ combined what is the difference between, say, $b^n$ and $b*$ in this regexp?

Comment: The intended interpretation is $\bigcup_n a^nb^nbbbb^*$

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ah, yes, sorry. Even though I got it the wrong way around, the hint stands as a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$S \rightarrow aSb/A $

$A \rightarrow \epsilon/a/aa/aaa/B$

$B \rightarrow bB/\epsilon$